# Why torch::jit::load() can only load files produced by torch::jit::save()

Tags: android-ndk, pytorch

I'd like to load a pytorch model weight & bias **.pt in android ndk project. I used pytorch mobile anddorid library to parse the model. When I used torch::load api, it cause linked error:

> headers/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/serialize.h:130: undefined reference to `torch::serialize::InputArchive::InputArchive()

> headers/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/serialize.h:131: undefined reference to `torch::serialize::InputArchive::load_from()

> headers/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/serialize.h:139: undefined reference to torch::serialize::InputArchive::try_read()

.Then I used torch::jit::load to parsed, but got execution error:

> terminating with uncaught exception of type c10::Error: `torch::jit::load()` received a file from `torch.save()`, but `torch::jit::load()` can only load files produced by `torch.jit.save()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the reason is [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/36568). C++ frontend api currently only supports loading jit saved tensor file. So the only solution is torch.load then torch.jit.save in python